# File upload not working with Retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit, okhttp

I was previously using apache to preform file upload:

```
FileBody fileBody = new FileBody(new File(path), mimeType);
FormBodyPart formBodyPart = new FormBodyPart("partName", fileBody);

MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity();
reqEntity.addPart(formBodyPart);

...
```

That would successfully upload the file with the part name of 'partName'

Switching to retrofit:

```
public interface UploadService {
    @Multipart
    @PUT("/somepath/{id}/upload")
    Call<ResponseBody> upload(@Path("id") String id, @Part("partName") RequestBody file);
}

var id = 123;
UploadService service = retrofit.create(UploadService.class);
File file = new File(path);
RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse(mimeType), file);

Response<ResponseBody> response = service.upload(id, requestBody).execute();
```

The partName of the request is not set.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: My answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33932916/how-to-post-an-image-to-server-in-android/33952163#33952163 using OkHttp, however, IMO, perhaps its logic can help you little

Comment: Awesome thanks. I can try a track down what is wrong with retrofit. And worst case just use okhttp as a work around.

Comment: IMO, you can check at `Headers.of("Content-Disposition", "form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"ic_launcher.png\"")` because with my web service (Asp.Net Web API), when android client did not set `filename` here, the web service did not think it is a multipart request

Comment: Apparantly file uploads are not working properly with PUT requests. Changing to POST should probably make it work. I'm currently investigating a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

My code to upload file with retrofit below:
With api:

```
@Multipart
@POST("url")
Call<Response> uploadImage(@Path("id") long id, @Part("file\"; filename=\"image.jpg") RequestBody file);
```

Retrofit request:

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
ApiClass apiClass = retrofit.create(ApiClass.class);
RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), imageFile);
Call<Response> call = apiClass.uploadImage(id, requestBody);
```

Hope it help you, good luck!